# Socket.io connection issue

Tags: android, socket.io, okhttp

I am using **Socket.io** for one to one chat. i used it before but never faced this kind of issue. My application getting crash after showing below error.

**Error which i am getting**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.MediaType.toString()' on a null object reference
        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$Request.onLoad(PollingXHR.java:271)
        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$Request.access$700(PollingXHR.java:148)
        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$Request$1.onResponse(PollingXHR.java:232)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:216)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

***What i have done till now?***

```
try {
            val user_email = preferenceManager.getLoggedInUserEmail()
            val ioOption = IO.Options()
            ioOption.query = "username=anyemail"
            ioOption.secure =true
            ioOption.reconnection=true

            SocketConstants.socketIOClient = IO.socket(SocketConstants.SOCKET_URL, ioOption)
            SocketConstants.socketIOClient?.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, object : Emitter.Listener {
                override fun call(vararg args: Any) {
                    SocketConstants.isSocketConnecting = false
                    Log.i(TAG, "Socket Connected Outside login check...."+args.size)
                }

            })
   SocketConstants.socketIOClient!!.connect()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

I am getting this Log before crash
***Socket Connected Outside login check....***

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I got solution of my problem.I don't know if this solution will work for other facing same but this worked for me.

What i did is

```
val ioOption = IO.Options()
            ioOption.query = "username=$user_email"
            ioOption.secure = true
            ioOption.reconnection = true
            ioOption.transports = arrayOf(WebSocket.NAME)

            SocketConstants.socketIOClient = IO.socket(SocketConstants.SOCKET_URL, ioOption)
```

***ioOption.transports = arrayOf(WebSocket.NAME)***

This line solved my problem. Just add trasports as "WebSocket".

Hope this will work for other if they face same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I have added Websocket.Name long ago still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

They release a new version 1.0.1 that fix the error https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client-java/commit/6f065b7a62603730979d43cec71af0046ca4ab7c (29 days ago). Be careful if you try to use v2.0.0, I have troubles to receive the socket messages so I used 1.0.1